# Using forms with Chrome console open

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I have the JavaScript console open in Chrome, I am often unable to use forms, fill in inputs, or click buttons in the browser because Chrome is highlighting HTML elements for me.

Sometimes, it stops, but I don't know what I am doing to make it stop.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or something to make Chrome not highlight HTML elements and let me use the form on the page with the console open?

Comment: Shortcut to start/stop inspecting is Cmd+Alt+C. But DevTools should not highlight anything by itself. You have to trigger 'inspecting' manually. Maybe what you are seeing is a bug? Can you post a video of what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This irritation can be avoided by using a different keyboard shortcut. `cmd+shift+c` makes chrome inspect elements on the page, even after you switch to the Javascript console. `cmd+option+j` opens the console and lets you go on behaving like a user.